# Can one do linear algebra using only a ruler and compass?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, euclidean-geometry

To what extend is it possible to represent matrices and vectors with configurations of points and lines in the plane, and then do common linear algebra operations on these matrices and vectors using a ruler and compass? Could the ancient greeks have done linear algebra using only Euclidean geometry?

For example, desirable operations might include matrix-vector multiplication, matrix-matrix addition, matrix-matrix multiplication, matrix inversion, LU factorization, QR factorization and so on. Presumably, anything involving eigenvalues would not be possible. This question is about arbritrary-sized $N \times M$ matrices (not just $2 \times 2$ matrices).

Has anyone ever attempted this? Of course this is a totally impractical way to do linear algebra; I'm just wondering as an intellectual curiosity.

This question was inspired by the following question that asks about doing least-squares using a compass and ruler:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507457/impractical-question-is-it-possible-to-find-the-regression-line-using-a-ruler-a

Comment: You'll run into dimensionality problems in general unless you restrict to specific problems as in the referenced question.

Comment: I think this is an interesting idea. A Greek mathematician would have been very comfortable with the idea of basis and span had it been presented to them, as that was analogous to how they did constructions. In fact I think eigenvalues would be more readily accessible to them because of their geometry. However, I think the biggest hurdle would be the difference in philosophy in proofs. Greek method of proofs often involved drawing correspondences between shapes and proving that $<$ and $>$ were impossibilities. Most linear algebra proofs are more direct and "constructive" than that by nature.

Comment: One thing that is impossible using only a ruler and compass is the computation of eigenvalues of arbitrary $3 \times 3$ matrices.